# Transfer App from LG to Droid

Tags: android

I need to test Android App specifically on LG Ally mobile. I am on windows and unable to find driver. I am unable to test it.
I can deploy app on Droid, however it doesn't work with Droid (I know Apps should be universal and should work independent of Device make, but this acts weird as it involves muting and unmuting of microphone and for some reason Droid gives up on me). 
Is there a way to download app on Droid and then transfer it to LG mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initally missed that you didnt have drivers for the Ally -

**You can get the app that installs the drivers [here](http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/phone-software-update.jsp) then you could deploy right to the device too**

You might be able to pull it off using ADB pull to get it off the droid. I do not know if you can pull them off though if you dont have root access, my device always has root via ADB, but try:

```
> cd c:\android\android-sdk-windows\tools\
> adb pull /data/app/myApplication.apk c:\Users\MyName\Desktop
```

when you do the `pull`, the /data/ path must be exact, it is case sensitive, so you must know the apk file name exactly.

then to install on the other device

```
> adb install c:\Users\MyName\Desktop\myApplication.apk
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a FileManager like [Astro](http://www.metago.net/astro/fm/download.php) to backup the app to the sd card and then put the sd card into the LG phone and run ASTRO again on the LG to install the app from the sd card.

You could also upload the APK to someplace on the web and then download it to your Phone and install it through the browser.